# Android - Can you combine an onClick method in Java, with if else statements to call an intent?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I'm trying to use if/else statements within my onClick method, to determine which activity to call next. I want to determine this based on scores I have saved and I am comparing them upon onClick. Code below.

```
// onClick method used with button "NEXT"
public void exchangeAOff(View view){

    // Comparing scores
    ScoreDatabase scoreDatabase=new ScoreDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    if (scoreDatabase.getScoreA() >= 50) {
        // This is where I'm unsure, can I use intents within if/else statements, within my onClick method???
        Intent teamAWin = new Intent (this, TeamAWins.class);
        startActivity(teamAWin);
    } else if (scoreDatabase.getScoreB() >= 50) {
        Intent teamBWin = new Intent (this, TeamBWins.class);
        startActivity(teamBWin);
    } else if (scoreDatabase.getScoreB() < 50 && scoreDatabase.getScoreA() < 50){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TeamAOffense.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an actual question here? What is it you are having trouble with?

Comment: yes u can.So what's the actual problem?

Comment: My app is crashing when I use the onClick method. I thought it had something to do with the way I've used the if/else statements within a java method for onClick.

Comment: Check my answer below. Don't use "this" keyword in Intent when using inside onClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

In your onClickListener write your code like this :

```
ScoreDatabase scoreDatabase=new ScoreDatabase(getApplicationContext());
Intent intent;        
if (scoreDatabase.getScoreA() >= 50) {

     intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, TeamAWins.class);

} else if (scoreDatabase.getScoreB() >= 50) {

     intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, TeamBWins.class);

} else if (scoreDatabase.getScoreB() < 50 && scoreDatabase.getScoreA() < 50){

     intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, TeamAOffense.class);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This worked, after a lot of other minor edits on other stuff. THANKS!